# Open E String is in Tune but fingered pitches are sharp

Tags: strings, violin, string-instruments

My last e string broke so I got a new one. My e string is in tune when I play it together with the open A (i.e. the violin is in tune), but the higher fingered pitches are all sharp. I know this is the case because on my previous e string I could play perfect fifths, but now I cannot. Also I can't play chords that I previously could. The new string that I am using is the Peter Infeld Chrome Steel, tin plated e string, and I am using it as a hook string. I have used this type of string before without problems. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the string is positioned properly in the slots in the bridge and the nut.

If that doesn't fix the problem, probably the bridge moved when you fitted the new string.

Make sure the top of the bridge is straight, and not with the E string end bent so it is closer to the fingerboard.

If you slacken off the string (but don't loosen in completely) you can push the bridge back into the correct shape with your fingers.

Unless you slackened off *all* the strings for some reason, it is unlikely the feet of the bridge will have moved on the instrument, so don't try to adjust them!

If you still have problems, you need to take the violin to a luthier, a teacher, or an experienced player who should be able to see what is wrong and fix it.

Comment: Bridge needs to be perpendicular to the violin body. Chances are it's tilted towards the neck. Hopefully it hasn't moved where it is in contact with the body.

Comment: Helpful Hint (TM)  I  learned from some luthier: once the bridge is properly placed, put a couple tiny dots of paint or whatever to mark the feet's positions. This lets you reset the bridge if disaster occurs.